# Is it possible to create stack in my AWS account and resources like (ec2, vpc, rds) created in client AWS account?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have written an AWS Lambda nodejs function for creating a stack in CloudFormation, using CloudFormation template and given input parameters from UI.

When I run my Lambda function with respected inputs, a stack is successfully creating and instances like (ec2, rds, and vpc, etc.) are also created and working perfectly.

Now I want to make this function as public and use this function with user AWS credentials.

So public user uses my function with his AWS credentials those resources should be created in his account and user doesn't want to see my template code.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [AWS Cloud Development Kit](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/) better, than directly using CloudFormation for this purpose. Although CDK may not be directly used within Lambda, [a workaround is mentioned here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/2637#issuecomment-496291068).

Answer (score 0):

AWS CloudFormation will create resources in the AWS Account that is associated with the credentials used to create the stack.

The person who creates the stack will need to provide (upload) a template file or they can reference a template that is stored in Amazon S3, which is accessible to their credentials (meaning that it is either public, or their credentials have been given permission to access the template in S3).